# SELECT specific combination

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

I'm sure this is easy. It's just difficult to find...

```
value_id   variation_id
1          1
2          1
1          2
3          2
```

Now I have a combination (1,2) and want to SELECT the variation. **(EDIT)** I want for example give (1,2) and get 1. Give (1,3) and get 2. **(/EDIT)** How can I achieve this?

I thought about GROUP BY value_id and somehow preserve that variation_id, that is hit by every value_id.

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the same (value_id,variation_id) combination never appears twice, then:

```
select variation_id from t 
  where value_id in(1,2)
  group by variation_id
  having count(variation_id)=2;
```

Otherwise

```
select variation_id from 
  (select distinct value_id, variation_id from t 
     where value_id in(1,2)) as tmp
  group by variation_id
  having count(variation_id)=2;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to select the pairs (1,1) (1,2) (2,1) (2,2):

```
select * from mytable where value_id in (1,2) and variation_id in (1,2)
```

Comment: Oh...Thank you, but this is not what I ment. I want for example give (1,2) and get 1. Give (1,3) and get 2. Your approach gives me variation_id 1 and 2.